# Что используется в java для выявления багов

Tags: java

Подскажите пожалуйста  для тестирования в c# используется Debug.Log()И Console.writeLine а что используется в Java.

Comment: Дюже удивительный вопрос. Если по аналогии, то ``java.util.logging`` и ``System.out.println()``.

Answer (score 3):

Про вывод в консоль и логгирование Вам уже ответили, стоит наверное упомянуть про профилировщики, например [`JVisualVM`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/visualvm/) или [`Java Mission Control` + `FlightRecorder`](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javaseproducts/mission-control/java-mission-control-1998576.html)

Профилировщики позволяют более глубоко проанализировать что происходит у Вас в программе, конечно всю эту информацию можно и в рантайме в лог записать, однако визуально как-то проще.

Пару слов о `JVisualVM`:

Он может работать как с запущенной программой, так и с логами, созданными другими средствами отладки, такие как `jstack`, `jmap` итд

---

Позволяет посмотреть как распределяется память в программе в целом, по этому графику можно понять как в Вашей программе обстоят дела с порождением и уничтожением объектов. Пила - верный признак избыточного использования новый объектов.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

Можно узнать что лежит в памяти, посмотреть где объекты были созданы (для этого надо в настройках найти и поставить галочку `record allocation stack traces`)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

Можно в графическом представлении узнать о том, как работают потоки:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Все это может быть очень полезным при поиске проблем в программах на java, однако так же я рекомендую научиться пользоваться консольными средствами отладки из состава `jdk`, я уже упоминал их `jstack`, `jmap` итд. ибо если надо снять информацию с запущенного сервера с доступом только по `ssh` визуальные профилировщики не помогут.

Answer (score 1):

В Java тоже есть инфраструктура логирования. Если говорить конкретно про логирование в Андроид, то это [Log](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/Log). А ещё есть линтеры, статические анализаторы, но самое главное - отладчик.